# Is it possible to use a checklist to enable and disable filters applied to the table in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

In Google Data Studio, I have a table connected to a data source and I have a **filter** called **DummyFilter**.

*Now I want the viewers of the chart to be able to decide to apply the filter to the table or not.*

Is this possible? Is there a way to do it using CHECKBOX or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, this is not possible.

In Data Studio, filters are not intended to be enabled/disabled during report visualization (as in PowerBI).

To workaround this, you can create a custom field with Yes/No values based on your condition, and then add this field in a ComboBox.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did to solve this. 
But when my data source has huge data to process, multiple custom field actually slows down the loading of the report.

Comment: Really? What's your Data Source? I have big Data Sources with dozens of calculated fields and I really do not feel a big performance penalty caused by them. Try using Big Query, if you're not using it yet. Data Studio and BigQuery play really nice together.

Comment: Yeah, I'm moving into Big Query now. Initially it was a MySQL.